# htaccess password protect conflict

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a problem with htaccess authentication in a wordpress project. I want to password protect a subdirectory (beta) but not the root directory (mywebpage). So, i have the following directories

```
mywebpage
  index.php
  beta
     index.php
     .htaccess
     .htpasswd
```

The problem is that when I try to access my webpage directory, I still get the login popup. But when the index file in the mywebpage is .html file then works just fine.

Here is the content of the .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "MySprts"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/web703/html/mywepage/beta/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put an empty .htaccess (e.g. with only `AuthName "MySprts"`) file in the root dir?

Comment: yes but nothing .. :/

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file goes in the directory you want it to effect.

root if you don't want password protection needs a .htaccess without a password directive.

/beta/ if you want password protection needs .htaccess with the password directive.

When apache web server loads a page it reads the root .htaccess first then the subdirectory .htaccess, repeating for every level of sub-directories. Each .htaccess can over-right the .htaccess directives closer to the root ... but does not change or effect those directories closer to the root.

Something is in .htaccess located higher up on the directory chain. Maybe it was created by cpanel? Could index.php be redirecting the traffic to the beta directory?

Comment: everything seems to be just as your instructions: root htacces contains just AuthName "MySprts" and /beta/ htaccess content is in my description

Comment: there is no other htaccess in chain and the /beta/ index its just a html form with some php code. no redirections. The weird is that if i change the root (/mywebpage/) index.php to index.html it works

Comment: take the .AuthName directive out of the root .htaccess and leave it in the beta .htaccess. None of the directives shown in your post need or should be in the root's or any parent's .htaccess.

Comment: What does /mywebpage/index.php contain? It sounds like it is redirecting into the beta directory.

Comment: Note: the browser caches redirects, (RewriteEngine) close the browser and re-open it to test.

Comment: ok now i know what you mean by redirecting. The prob was that the style files was in the beta folder. :)